# Inputing data from java gui to existing excel spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, netbeans

I am still new to java so please bear with me.  I have searched but can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I have used NetBeans to create a simple GUI Java application.  I need my program to take all of the text fields from the java application and import them into an already created excel spreadsheet.  I need to know where to start to look for information to do this.  In my search I have come accross Apache POI-HSSF but not sure if thats what I need.

Example:

**Java application has two text fields that the user types in.  Name and Phone number**

**At the bottom when the user clicks submit, I want those two text fields to input in the spreadsheet.**

**Lets say assign name to column A and phone number to column B**

**I would also like for each time the person clicks submit, the info writes into the next available row...so the data does not overwrite it just adds.**

**I already have a spreadsheet set up and just want to keep adding data to it.**

Sorry if this has been asked before.  I have searched and can't quite find the answer.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

**GUI:** If your application is simple, I strongly recommend you using its embedded **[Swing  GUI Builder (Matisse)](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)** for building an application, which later you can integrate to **[NetBeans Platform (RCP)](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/)** if it gets pretty sophisticated.

[Check official Java tutorials and introduction.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/index.html)

**EXCEL:** You were headed the right direction - [**Apache POI**](http://poi.apache.org/), HSSF for .xls (Excel 97-2003), XSSF for .xlsx (Excel 2007+).

[Apache POI quick guide of capabilities.](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Hope this help. Happy starting, welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using the swing gui builder within netbeans (design tab).  I guess I'm off to explore Apache POI HSSF.  Any good tutorials on how to use it?

Comment: I provided the link to the quick guide, this should be well enough for the start. If you like my answer, you can vote it up, if you don't you can vote it down and if you think this is the best answer to your case - accept it as the correct answer. No problem.